# How to stop JavaScript event after reaching specific value

Tags: javascript, dom, events

I have a simple dynamic calculation template. Here as you can see, the template starts with **a + b**. when the user click add button, two types of dropdown lists will display based on the last element of the template. if calculation finishes with value, operations dropdown will display, or vice versa. the problem here, the dropdown should stop displaying when the template is finished as a complete mathematical exercise. like **a + b + c**, **a + b + c + d** and here dropdown should disappear each time when the last element is value, not operation.

```js
    document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click', e => {
      const countItem = document.querySelector('.lists').childElementCount
      if (countItem % 2 == 0) {
        dropdown('dropdown-value')

      } else {
        dropdown('dropdown-operation')
      }
    });

    document.querySelectorAll('.menu-list').forEach(list => list.addEventListener('click', e => {
      const span = document.createElement('span');
      span.textContent = e.target.textContent

      document.querySelector('.lists').appendChild(span)
      document.querySelector('.dropdown-value').style.display = 'none'
      document.querySelector('.dropdown-operation').style.display = 'none'
    }));

    dropdown = (element) => {
      document.querySelector(`.${element}`).style.display = 'block'
    }
```

```css
  .container {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    margin-left: 2rem;
  }

  a {
    margin-left: 1rem;
  }

  ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .lists span {
    padding: 1rem;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    margin-right: .2rem;
  }

  .add {
    position: relative;
    background: #290fff;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .dropdown-operation,
  .dropdown-value {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    background: #f1f1f1;
  }

  .dropdown-value li,
  .dropdown-operation li {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="lists">
      <span>a</span>
      <span>+</span>
      <span>b</span>
    </div>

    <a class="add"> Add

      <!-- Dropdowns -->
      <div class="dropdown-value" style="display: none;">
        <ul class="menu-list">
          <li>a</li>
          <li>b</li>
          <li>c</li>
          <li>d</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown-operation" style="display: none;">
        <ul class="menu-list">
          <li>*</li>
          <li>/</li>
          <li>+</li>
          <li>-</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you're talking about, but you could just change the if/else to be `if (countItem == 2) { dropdown('dropdown-value'); } if (countItem == 3) { dropdown('dropdown-operation'); }` Then, since `countItem` will be 4 on the next click, nothing will happen.

Comment: You got What I want. I though about  doing like this, but the exercise  might continue, that is why there should be kind of logic to stop displaying dropdown

Comment: I mean you could just `return;` but you'd still need to figure out some condition under which it should stop. I don't think anyone else is going to be able to tell you that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```js
listen('.open');
listen('.dropdown-operation');

function listen(elem) {
  document.querySelector(elem).addEventListener('click', e => {
    const countItem = document.querySelector('.lists').childElementCount
    if (countItem % 2 == 0) {
      dropdown('dropdown-value')

    } else {
      dropdown('dropdown-operation')
    }
  });
}

document.querySelectorAll('.menu-list').forEach(list => list.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  span.textContent = e.target.textContent

  document.querySelector('.lists').appendChild(span)
  document.querySelector('.dropdown-value').style.display = 'none'
  document.querySelector('.dropdown-operation').style.display = 'none'
}));

const dropdown = (element) => {
  document.querySelector(`.${element}`).style.display = 'block'
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

a {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.lists span {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  margin-right: .2rem;
}

.add {
  position: relative;
  background: #290fff;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-operation,
.dropdown-value {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

.dropdown-value li,
.dropdown-operation li {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="lists">
    <span>a</span>
    <span>+</span>
    <span>b</span>
  </div>

  <a class="add">
    <div class='open'>add</div>

    <!-- Dropdowns -->
    <div class="dropdown-value" style="display: none;">
      <ul class="menu-list">
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li>c</li>
        <li>d</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-operation" style="display: none;">
      <ul class="menu-list">
        <li>*</li>
        <li>/</li>
        <li>+</li>
        <li>-</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```